# How to compare the stability of 3,4-Dimethylcyclopentene and Cyclopentane, 1-methyl-2-methylene

Tags: organic-chemistry

Two alkenes are given as follows:

[image: 3,4-Dimethylcyclopentene],
[image]

How do I compare their stability?

Denoting the first compound as (A) and the second as (B).
Both the alkenes have same number of $\alpha$ hydrogens, which is $3$. Hence in terms of stability by hyperconjugation they should be similar. However the structure (A) contains $2$ carbons in $sp^2$ hybridisation "inside" the ring, whereas the compound (B) contains only one such ring carbon. Now since the typical bond angle of $sp^2$ is given as $120^\circ$, it is was intuitive for me to think that structure (A) would suffer a higher angle strain since the angles of a pentagon are $108^\circ$, however it seems incorrect since the solution of my paper did not consider this. Please help me to figure out what is that I am doing wrong and what the correct order should be, or whether they have equal stabilities.

Comment: Heat of Combustion?

Comment: The question stated to tell which alkenes are more stable than (A) and (B) was one of the options. They mostly likely did mean to ask the "Stability" of the double bonds, so heat of hydrogenation I think.

Comment: The problem does not state the stereochemistry in A.  Hydrogenation of B will likely give a mixture. The stereochemistry of A should be defined. Heat of combustion is the best bet.

Comment: @user55119 How should I be comparing the heat of combustion? The number of carbons is the same so that factor is ruled out.

Comment: Heats of formation are computed from heats of combustion. Unfortunately, these compounds are not listed at the NIST site. https://webbook.nist.gov/chemistry/. Sometimes heats of formation can be estimated using desmotic reactions. http://ursula.chem.yale.edu/~chem220/chem220js/STUDYAIDS/thermo/homodesmotic/homodesmotic.html